# VSCode Debug and Jest: No breakpoints running with npm, CWD error running with node

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, jestjs, gatsby

I am trying to get breakpoints to hit in Jest Debug for VS Code.

This launch config runs but does not hit breakpoints:

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Test",
    "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
    "runtimeArgs": ["test"],
    "port": 9229
}
```

This launch config does not run, but it looks like it hits breakpoints.

It opens `fs.js` at a debugger breakpoint with this error:

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, access 'node_modules/jest-cli/bin/package.json'

Like it's looking for the workspace's  package.json file inside the jest bin directory.

```
{
    "type": "node",
    "request": "launch",
    "name": "Jest All",
    "program": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/jest",
    "args": ["--runInBand"],
    "console": "integratedTerminal",
    "internalConsoleOptions": "neverOpen"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a package.json file one directory up. I deleted it, but still got the same error. I fixed it by copying it to a new directory further up on my path, I believe so VS Code could detect it was a new workspace.

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was that inside VSCodes Debugging Panel inside the Breakpoints section, I had `All Exceptions` checked. Unchecking this allowed the debugger to work as I expected.

Also the issue did not happen when checking the `Uncaught Exceptions` Breakpoint handler. `All Exceptions` actually catches all not just inside your but also inside others code, **regardless** if they are handled or not.